# xslt output doctype before comments

Tags: html, xml, xslt, doctype

I'm trying to output paul irish' conditional comments around the html tag, in a page generated by xslt

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
```

etcetera. This works

```
<xsl:comment>[if lt IE 7]&gt; &lt;html class="no-js ie6"&gt; &lt;![endif]</xsl:comment>
```

but unfortunately, *some* parsers decide to put the doctype declaration before the first real element, and *after* any preceding xml comments. xsltproc puts the doctype before the comments, saxon puts it after the comments. its apparently unspecified what the good behaviour is, but ie wants the doctype to be the first thing in the page, period.

In short, I'm trying to find a way to make saxon output a doctype before any comments. any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saxon is right, the specifications are clear: when serializing the result document the `doctype` declaration must be put immediately before the first element. This is specified in both [XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-XML-Output-Method) and [XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#XML_DOCTYPE):

> If the doctype-system attribute is specified, the xml output method should output a document type declaration **immediately before** the first element.

To solve this you can add manually the `doctype` declaration in your document, using the `xsl:text` element with the `disable-output-escaping` attribute set to `yes`. For example you can output a standard HTML5 doctype, without any public identifier, which would be otherwise impossible to do in XSLT.

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE html></xsl:text>
```

Comment: Anyone who does this, dont forget to remove the doctype-system from the output tag

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I didnt do this .. I ended up doing it in javascript

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    if ($.browser.version<9) $('html').addClass('lt-ie9');
    if ($.browser.version<8) $('html').addClass('lt-ie8');
    if ($.browser.version<7) $('html').addClass('lt-ie7');
```

}